# Problems setting Eclipse IDE for cross-compiling for Arm based PandaBoard-ES

Tags: c++, eclipse, arm, cross-compiling, pandaboard

I am trying to set up the Eclipse IDE for cross-compiling C++ code, which should run on the  Arm based PandaBoard-ES device.

My machine runs an 64Bit Fedora 20. I followed this [how-to](http://denizbeker.blogspot.de/2013/08/cross-compile-for-pandaboard-es-by.html) and after installing the 32Bit version of glibc (*glibc.i686*) I was able to build the "hello world" project.

My problem is, that when I copy the binary to the Pandaboard device (Running Debian Jessie 3.16.0-armv7-x3 ) I am not able to execute it. (*No such file or directory*)

Could please someone give me a hint what to do ?

EDIT:

Here is the output of *file* for midnight-commander binary (from repos) and the cross-compiled binary

```
PandaBoard3:~$ file /usr/bin/mc
  /usr/bin/mc: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=31c7410ced0a9b54f97a28e6cbabf97afd4ecee3, stripped

PandaBoard3:~$ file ./Pandaboard\ crosscompile 
 ./Pandaboard crosscompile: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have libc or ABI mismatch. Just run `file` on compiled binary and on some working binary on you Jessie. You should see the difference.

Fedora is not the best distro for cross-compiling software for Debian. You have basically two possibilities:

1. take Debian Jessie x86 as development host. This way you would have the same GCC, libc etc. on both systems. [Here](https://wiki.debian.org/EmdebianToolchain) you can read, how to install a toolchain from Emdebian repo. Also take a look at `xapt`. It will let you install cross-compiled dependencies like Qt, Boost etc.
2. take some "from scratch" distro like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/). Such a distro will take care about both toolchain and rootfs, so that is is always compatible.

Comment: Oh thank you, you just teached me a new command. :-)
But I do not see much difference (I took midnght commander binary as example)

PandaBoard3:~$ file /usr/bin/mc
/usr/bin/mc: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=31c7410ced0a9b54f97a28e6cbabf97afd4ecee3, stripped

PandaBoard3:~$ file ./Pandaboard\ crosscompile 
./Pandaboard crosscompile: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped

Comment: At least kernel headers version is different and I don't know, if `file` shows if it is hardware-float or software-float. I have a Debian image, that is `armhf`. What does `ldd` say to `./Pandaboard crosscompile`? If you don't have `ldd` try: `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 <executable>`

Comment: ldd just prints, that the cross-compiled binary is not dnymicaly linked. I think it will be wiser to follow you recomendations. I thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is years too late and might be rather rudimentary, but did you check the file permissions for the binary you were trying to run? Run ls -alv and check to see if the file has the execute permission enabled for your user.